# Matrix Text rain effect in Processing 3.3

Tags: processing

I'm working on making a matrix text rain effect in Processing 3.3 as a simple starter project for learning the processing library and Java. My code so far:

```java
class Symbol {
  int x, y;
  int switchInterval = round(random(2, 50));
  float speed;
  char value;

  Symbol(int x, int y, float speed) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = speed;
  }

  //Sets to random symbol based on the Katakana Unicode block
  void setToRandomSymbol() {
    if(frameCount % switchInterval == 0) {
      value = char((int) random(0x30A0, 0x3100));
    }
  }

  //rains the characters down the screen and loops them to the top when they
  // reach the bottom of the screen
  void rain() {
    if(y <= height) {
      y += speed;
    }else {
      y = 0;
    }
  }
}

Symbol symbol;

class Stream {
  int totalSymbols = round(random(5, 30));
  Symbol[] symbols = new Symbol[500];
  float speed = random(5, 20);

  //generates the symbols and adds them to the array, each symbol one symbol 
  //height above the one previous
  void generateSymbols() {
    int y = 0;
    int x = width / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i <= totalSymbols; i++) {
      symbols[i] = new Symbol(x, y, speed);
      symbols[i].setToRandomSymbol();
      y -= symbolSize;
    }
  }

  void render() {
    for(Symbol s : symbols) {
      fill(0, 255, 70);
      s.setToRandomSymbol();
      text(s.value, s.x, s.y);
      s.rain();
    }
  }
}
```

Ok, so that was a lot of code, Let me explain my dilemma. The issue I'm having is that when I run the code I get a NullpointerException at the `s.setToRandomSymbol();` method call in the for each loop in the render function. The weird part about this NullPointerException error and the part I'm not understanding is that it's being thrown on a method that doesn't take in any arguments that could be coming back empty, and the method itself is void, so it shouldn't be returning anything, right? Why is this returning Null and what did I do wrong to have it return this way?

Comment: What is `width` and where do you set it?

Comment: `width` is a built-in variable in the processing library that is equal to the width of the window.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. When I try to run your code I get an error because `symbolSize` is never defined. Even if I fix that error I just get a blank sketch, because you haven't included your `setup()` or `draw()` functions. Instead of posting all of your code, try to create a small example that we can run, and we'll go from there.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to do this in future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you come up with a random number betwen 5 and 30:

int totalSymbols = round(random(5, 30));

Then you create an array that holds `500` instances of your `Symbol` class:

```
Symbol[] symbols = new Symbol[500];
```

Note that this array holds 500 `null` values at this point.

Then you add a maximum of 30 instances of `Symbol` to your array:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= totalSymbols; i++) {
  symbols[i] = new Symbol(x, y, speed);
```

Note that this array now holds at least 470 `null` values at this point.

Then you iterate over all 500 indexes:

```
for(Symbol s : symbols) {
  s.setToRandomSymbol();
```

But remember that at least 470 of these indexes are `null`, which is why you're getting a `NullPointerException`.

Some basic debugging would have told you all of this. I would have started by adding a basic `println()` statement just before you get the error:

```
for(Symbol s : symbols) {
  println("s: " + s);
  s.setToRandomSymbol();
```

This would have showed you that you're iterating over `null` values.

Anyway, to fix your problem you need to stop iterating over your entire array, or you need to stop making room for indexes you never use.

In the future, **please** try to narrow your problem down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting. Note that this much smaller example program shows your error:

```
String[] array = new String[10];
array[0] = "test";
for(String s : array){
  println(s.length());
}
```